# How to accept one version for all manual merge changes in clearcase?

Tags: merge, clearcase

When I am having to manually merge a file using xmerge, I have to click through every change manually and select a number to be the version to use. But sometimes I just want to accept one version for every change. Is there a shortcut/setting for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One shortcut is the button `Resolve and Advance`.

Once clicked, you can then repeatedly click on one version button, until there is no more merge conflict to solve (then save and close)